# Application crashes after reading 35-40 Webcam frames

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been successful in detecting faces captured from webcam, however after capturing about 35-40 frames, the application crashes, i have posted only relevant part of my code, `_Image` is a class that i have implemented.

```
_Image *Obj;
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
if ( !capture ) 
{
   fprintf( stderr, "\n\n---ERROR: capture is NULL---\n" );
}
IplImage * frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
 // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
while (1) 
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if ( !frame ) {
          fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Webcam frame is null...Unexpected Error - Exiting" );    
          getchar();
          exit(0);
    }
    Obj = new _Image(frame);
    if(Obj==0)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "\nERROR: Out of Memory!!\n" );
        cvReleaseImage(&frame );
        cvDestroyAllWindows();
        // Release the capture device 
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
                        exit(0);
    }
    flag = Obj->detect_face_in_image();
    if(flag!=0)
    {
        Obj->add_frame_name();
        Obj->webcam_reader( *Obj); 
    }
         // Do not release the frame!
    delete Obj;
    cvNamedWindow( "WEBCAM", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage ( "WEBCAM", frame);
    if ( (cvWaitKey(10)) == 27 )
    {
                  cvReleaseImage(&frame );
        cvDestroyAllWindows();
        // Release the capture device 
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
                        break;
    }
}
```

However i don't get this kind of a crash if a change my code a bit to play AVI files, this only happens with Webcam. I get the Windows XP `send or dont send error report`, no specific error message before crash.

Comment: You don't mention what *kind* of crash you are witnessing (access violation, stack overflow, etc...), nor whereabouts in this code the crash occurs. What do you see in your debugger?

Comment: The program just crashes out, like at times you end tasks from Task Manager, just like that... there is not specific way to find out the exact reason... how should i use the debugger here?

Comment: @Johnsyweb - When i removed the `delete Obj` the problem got fixed, but wont this result in a memory leak, how to counter this?

Comment: Hello,

if you are developping for Windows, chances are that you are using Visual Studio. Then why not try to use the debugguer ? It will catch the crashes and point you where they happen.

Comment: I haven't done any Windows-based development in years, but I'm sure MSVS will give you a stack trace when a crash occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to give you the reason as long as the code is incomplete.

You are passing *Obj to Obj->webcam_reader() - why anyway, if Obj is already passed as the this pointer.

Depending on how webcam_reader is defined, you might make a copy of Obj at this point (if you do not pass by reference). If that object cannot be copied safely, you might get a problem. This might be the case if you did not implement a copy constructor, but using manually allocated dynamic memory in that class. In this case, only a pointer is copied and freed twice.

As said, people can only speculate about the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
cvWaitKey(10);
```

to

```
cvWaitKey(25);
```

or maybe

```
cvWaitKey(35);
```

Comment: It's possible that the webcam crashes because you want to access frames quicker than it's able to capture. It may not be the solution, but an easy check.

Comment: But looking into the code, it also seems that a possible error is a leak, or you try to free a memory which is protected. keep in mind that the capture object always returns a pointer to the same memory block, where the new frame was copied by the codec (video) or driver (camera), and cannot be freed by your app